# Undefined variable $header (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Dpo-v02\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

When I click the reset password button send in mailtrap it shows an error that in my blade has undefined variable header and i dont know what to do for solution.

Im using laravel 8 with laravel breeze and laravel breezy. Im stuck in reset password function in laravel 8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            @include('layouts.navigation')

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <header class="bg-white shadow">
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    {{ $header ?? '' }}
                </div>
            </header>

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                {{ $slot ?? '' }}
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, post code not images as the image goes down and the question is unsuable...

Answer (score 0):

**add slot name="header" to your pages**

```
<x-slot name="header"> 
            <div class="flex justify-center sm:justify-between">
                <h2 class="hidden my-2 font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight sm:block">
                    {{ __('Dashboard') }}
                </h2>  
            </div>
</x-slot>
```

Comment: Can you explain me how does adding slot name="header" can solve my problem so that i can understand it. Thank you :>

Comment: copy and paste this code to blade file

Comment: I add the code in app.blade it doesnt really solve anything.